# Finding inverse with parameter

Tags: functions

How can I find $f^{-1}(-1)$ of $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+4ax+4$? To be honest I don't know where to start from.

Comment: How about solving the equation $f(x)=-1$?

Comment: I don't know how to solve it that's the problem

Comment: in my book it actually asks for the derivate of the inverse but in order to find it i need to know the inverse.Is there any other way?

Comment: Please post the whole exercise,finding the derivative of the inverse should be easier then finding the inverse itself. This is called the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}(-1) = b \implies f(b) = -1 \implies b^3+2b^2+4ab + 4 = -1 \implies b^3+2b^2+4ab+5 = 0$. Thus $b$ is the solution of this cubic equation in $a$. The solutions are well known and is known as Viete's theorem that can be looked up in wikipedia or any book on polynomial equations in the press or online nowadays.

Comment: might be useful to have a look here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: is there no way to solve this easier?

Comment: I also thought that it was a question about $(f^{-1})'(-1)$. For your question, there is no other way.